# É possível usar ng-model com contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu preciso utilizar uma `div`com o atributo `contenteditable` e  o resultado desse valor preciso colocar num `ng-model`.

Eu fiz assim, mas parece não estar funcionando como esperado:

```
<div contenteditable ng-model="observacao"></div>
```

Como fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Já responderam isso a um tempo atrás aqui esta o link espero ter ajudado abraço! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583651/contenteditable-with-ng-model-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tag `contenteditable` não funcionará diretamente com o `ng-model` do **AngularJS** porque a maneira de renderizar do mesmo atualiza o elemento no documento a cada mudança.

Você deve envolvê-lo com uma [Diretiva](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) personalizada para isso:

**JS:**

```
angular.module('customControl', ['ngSanitize']).
directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // Specify how UI should be updated
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
      };

      // Listen for change events to enable binding
      element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
        scope.$evalAsync(read);
      });
      read(); // initialize

      // Write data to the model
      function read() {
        var html = element.html();
        // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
        // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
        if ( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
          html = '';
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm">
 <div contenteditable
      name="myWidget" ng-model="userContent"
      strip-br="true"
      required>Troque me!</div>
  <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Obrigatorio!</span>
 <hr>
 <textarea ng-model="userContent"></textarea>
</form>
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583651/contenteditable-with-ng-model-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Veja se este artigo ajuda
Ele mostra como criar  a diretiva do contenteditable

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-contenteditable